# Installing NVIDIA 361.45.11?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics, ppa

I was checking [recent packages](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) and figured out that NVIDIA 361.45.11 [recent version] is available [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/6457699/+listing-archive-extra).

I am new here and cant understand how to install this [package (NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.45.11)](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/6457699/+listing-archive-extra) via PPA, how can i install this package using PPA?

Answer (score 1):

Try this first:

1. Go to settings -> software updates -> additional drivers.
2. Wait while Ubuntu searches for compatible drivers.
3. If NVIDIA 361.45.11 is available then select it and click the Apply Changes button.
4. If it is not available, use the newest compatible NVIDIA driver that is listed.

Alternatively, try this:

Use the steps shown on the website below to download the drivers directly from Ubuntu's repository:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Final note: Use the newest compatible drivers only. I highly recommend picking a driver from the list under Additional Drivers rather than manually intalling one to avoid issues that may be caused by potentially incompatible drivers.

Answer (score 0):

To install **Nvidia Drivers**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-361
```

If you'd like to check available versions of nvidia drivers just press the **Tab** button after typing the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-
```

Alternatively, you can use Software & Updates application where you have to just navigate to **Additional Drivers** section where you will see something like this

[image]

Just select the appropriate version of nvidia driver and click on apply changes after installing the drivers you might need to restart your pc.

**Note**: To check if the nvidia drivers are installed or not you can run the following command and you'll see something like this

[image]

Happy Ubuntu!